# How to resize ThreeJS Renderer in Firefox & Edge

Tags: three.js

I have a simple web app with a three.js webgl view. The page is responsive, so I need to resize the 3d view as the window size changes. This works fine in Chrome, but does nothing in Firefox, and resizes but renders a black canvas in Edge.

The code I'm using is:

```
canvasWidth = canvasHeight = window.innerWidth < 786 ? window.innerWidth : Math.min(window.innerWidth*0.35, 500)
renderer.setSize(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
camera.aspect = canvasWidth / canvasHeight;
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
```

This code is executed on window resize.

The app is available at http://bit.ly/1oecKUe

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Does the resize of your canvas work in Firefox when you directly use `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` like this:

```
camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
```

This is the normal approach three.js examples resize their canvas. Maybe there is a problem in the way you calculate the `canvasWidth` and `canvasHeight` variables...

Comment: The values of canvasWidth and canvasHeight don't change things. I added a line of code to the original question to show how these values are calculated.

Comment: Well, if you calculate the `canvasWidth` and `canvasHeight` in this way, the canvas won't change in many cases. Besides, if i reduces the width of my Firefox to a very small value, i actually do have a resize effect. Anyway, i recommend to make the resize conditional on both canavs dimensions (not only width).

Comment: For me the size of the webGL canvas never changes on Firefox, regardless of how much the window size changes.